# Handle html code in comment box

Tags: php, html, mysql, handler

I have a website where users leave a comment which will be inserted into database.

After that the user will be redirected to the same page with updated and inserted comment display.

I used `php` and `mysql` for this. It is working fine.

But for safer side, I inserted html code in `textbox` and it is executing.

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to call a function with arguments</p>

<button onclick=myFunction(Harry Potter,Wizard)>Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(name,job)
{
alert(Welcome  + name +, the  + job);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In my page try button is coming with an alert message.
I don't have any idea how to handle this.

Can any one help me?

Comment: `but for safe side when i inserted html code in textbox it is executing.` what do you mean by that? you don't want people to insert html tags in your comment box?

Comment: oh and your javascript has issues. you don't quote onclick and strings you send to function

Comment: Please use punctuation and capitalize first letter!

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FSQM/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to call a function with arguments</p>

<button onclick='myFunction("Harry Potter","Wizard")'>Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(name,job)
{
alert("Welcome"  + name +", the"  + job);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I believe OP doesn't want people to be able to leave html comments and he doesn't want to display alerts... Maybe I'm wrong, and I would like OP to confirm this.

Comment: I don't think anyone understands the question. I'm just fixing the code.